# Active workbook is randomly changed after macro execution

Tags: vba, excel, macros

After I run a macro(which selects records from sql server, no reference to another workbook), one of the other open workbooks is randomly activate.
The macro is in book1, I run the macro from book1.
At the end, book2(or book3 etc) is activate. Why ?!
I tried to put just before End Sub

```
Dim Wb As Workbook  
Set Wb = Active/ThisWorkbook  
Wb.Activate
```

or

```
msgbox "ok"
```

but still fly to another open workbook(the message box pop up on book2)
This thing not happens every time, just sometimes, randomly.
Thank you

update: Since I fixed a cirrcular refference in book2, seems to stop.

Comment: Is the macro putting the results to a new book?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Wb.Name` returns ?

Comment: Have you tried a watch on Application.Activeworkbook and breaking on change, not sure if this works, as not able to test just at mo.

Comment: I think it's because `Set Wb = Activeworkbook` Sets Wb variable to the workbook which is active just before running the macro. Use `Set Wb = ThisWorkbook` Instead.

Answer (score 1):

[See Difference Between ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426907/difference-between-thisworkbook-name-and-activeworkbook-name-in-vba/35426954#35426954)

```
Sub Bus()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
Debug.Print Wb.Name

Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Debug.Print Wb.Name


End Sub
```

If you put above code in Book2. Module 1 and Select Book1 and run it

You will get following output in the immediate Window:

```
Book1
Book2
```

[image]

Comment: I get book1, no matter activeworkbook or thisworkbook.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of setup and full code if available ?