# ThisDocument object reference

Tags: vba, ms-word

How `ThisDocument` object refers to the docm file contents, which containing the code?

I had insert a module under the *.docm project which contains this code:

```
Sub test()
   Debug.Print ThisDocument.Name
End Sub
```

Returns `Normal.dotm` as result.

But it is expected returning the current **docm** file's *name*.

How can set 'Thisdocument' Object subroutines refers to the current `docm` file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the tagging and the question it's not clear exactly what you have. This code is running in Excel? But the code is working with Word? `ThisDocument` is an object in the Word object model, not in Excel, and refers to the "code container".

Comment: @CindyMeister@: Actually you right. I was edited my question.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain `Sub test` is in that docm Project and not in the Normal project? In the VB Editor click in the Sub then look in the Project window (usually to the left, where Normal is certainly one of the projects listed). By default, Normal is where Word stores new macros, so code often ends up there instead of where the coder thinks it is...

Comment: It may happens. I'm not at work and that project is at my work. I will discover tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by  Cindy Meister, From the tagging and the question it's not clear exactly what you have (or have in your mind). However **assuming that you are aiming something highly tricky and unconventional** with both Excel & Word applications involved. In normal condition `ThisDocument` will never refer to `Normal.dotm`(from a module under the *.xlsm project) but since you made it happen and also aim to "set `Thisdocument` Object refers to the current xlsm file", I would have try it like this from a module in xlsm file.

```
Global ThisDocument As Object
Sub calltest()
Dim wd As Word.Application
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Visible = True                 'for demo only
Set ThisDocument = wd.Templates(1)   'This will result Normal.dotm (as you are experiencing - may be similar code is already in the calling routine)
test
Set ThisDocument = ThisWorkbook     'This will result workbook Containing the module with code
test
End Sub
Sub test()
Debug.Print ThisDocument.Name
End Sub
```

Obviously it is assumed Reference to Microsoft Word XX Object Library had aleady been taken.

Comment: Excuse me. I was wrong in my question. my mean was `docm`, but because some mind confuse! I typed `xlsm` at wrong. I apologize

Comment: Never mind. It happens to all of us. But one thing for sure, I have learned greatest  techniques from  silliest mistakes.  Hope problem resolved with Cindy Meister ‘s comments.

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of the Excel file which contains the code you are running:

```
ThisWorkbook.Name
```

Get the name of the Excel file that your code is currently referencing:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

If you are running code from a Word doc that is referencing an Excel file, you would use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

This post goes into more detail on ActiveWorkbook vs ThisWorkbook.
[Difference between Thisworkbook.name and Activeworkbook.name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426907/difference-between-thisworkbook-name-and-activeworkbook-name-in-vba/35426954)

Comment: Excuse me. I was wrong in my question. my mean was `docm`, but because some mind confuse! I typed `xlsm` at wrong. I apologize