# Improper use of a Property

Tags: excel, vba

The code is supposed to compare two excel files and then create a new excel file showing the differences.

On the first sheet of the file, I’ve created a button and then opened it opened and put the code in. However, when I run the code I get an error saying

> improper use of a Property

and .Worksheets  is marked.
Or the problem can be something related to  `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`

I have done some research online and was unsuccessful so I’m hoping to get a bit of help.

Option Explicit

```
Sub Compare2WorkSheets(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
Dim report As Workbook 
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim difference As Long
Dim row As Long, col As Integer
Set report = Workbooks.Add

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws1row = .Rows.Count
    ws1col = .Columns.Count
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ws2row = .Rows.Count
    ws2col = .Columns.Count
End With

maxrow = ws1row
maxcol = ws1col

If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

difference = 0

For col = 1 To maxcol
    For row = 1 To maxrow
    colval1 = ""
    colval2 = ""
    colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
    colval2 = ws2.Cells(row, col).Formula

    If colval1 <> colval2 Then
    difference = difference + 1
    Cells(row, col).Formula = colval1 & "<> " & colval2
    Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = 255
    Cells(row, col).Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next row
Next col

Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 25
report.Saved = True

If difference = 0 Then
report.Close False
End If
Set report = Nothing

MsgBox difference & " cells contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets"

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1")` should be `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Also, use the correct quotation marks. `“”` should not be used, use `""` instead

Comment: I edited the code and used the correct quotation. Now I'm getting "index outside the valid range"

Comment: Does the sheet named "Sheet1" exist in the workbook that is currently active? I would strongly advise you ***not*** to refer to active workbooks. Instead, declare a workbook or worksheet variable and set that with preferably the worksheet codename, and if not possible use the sheet's name or index.

Comment: when I first created the sheet is was called "Tabelle1" so I renamed them into Sheet1 without any spaces.  I'm sorry but as it for now I'm a total beginner and not sure If I know how to do that

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are adding a new workbook with line `Set report = Workbooks.Add` so that new Workbook will have default names in the sheets. Those default names depends on your language settings. Also, when creating a new workbook, **it becomes the active one** so actually when later on you do `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` you are using the new workbook, which is a new one, so it's totally in blank. That may cause the fail If you are trying to activate a sheet in the workbook where you are executing this code, use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Also, if you are newbie with VBA, I strongly suggest you to read [Difference between Thisworkbook.name and Activeworkbook.name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426907/difference-between-thisworkbook-name-and-activeworkbook-name-in-vba)

Comment: The read the link and now I understand the differences. I switched to using "ThisWorkbook" but now I get en Object required error at "colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula". The code just doesn't whant to give me peace

Comment: In the code you posted, you never declare `ws1` or `ws2`. First, define those variables (google about **Option Explicit** to prevent non declared variables). Second, you need to assign those variables to worksheets using **Set**. Check [Declare and Set Worksheet](http://codevba.com/excel/set_worksheet.htm#.XVKDn-Mzbcs)

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns  Can you help me declare ws1 for sheet1 and ws2 for sheet2 ? would really appreciate it

Comment: @TimStack answer does it pretty good. To declare the variable, you need `Dim ws1 as Worksheet`. To assign it you need `Set ws1 = AnyWorkbook.Worksheets("nameofworksheet")` where `AnyWorkbook` is a specific workbook (could be `ThisWorkbook`, or `ActiveWorkbook` or `Report`, don't know what you need. You will have to figure out

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns,  I edited the code above. I think I declared everything right but when I run the code when the report while is creating  the file is not responding.  I just want to compare sheet1 & sheet2 from one  excel file and  then output the differences on a new excel file

Comment: You've set both variables to refer to exact same worksheet.... how are you going to compare?

Comment: I changed Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) to Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2). Same outcome the render file is created but not responding

Comment: In both cases you are using `Thisworkbook`, so you are comparing two sheets of same workbook (the one that holds the macro). Is that right? According to your question, you want to compare 2 Excel files, that means 2 different workbooks.

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns     yes that is the goal comparing two different Excel files. I would keep Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) the same ( holds the macro ). How would I do it for the other file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, I would use a variable to refer to the worksheet of a specific workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
 Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
 Dim report As Workbook, ws As Worksheet 'Declare ws to be a Worksheet variable
 Dim difference As Long, row As Long, col As Integer

 Set report = Workbooks.Add

 'Set the ws variable to be the first worksheet in the newly opened workbook
 Set ws = report.Worksheets(1)

 'You can then use the ws variable to refer to that specific worksheet
 'The variable is not affected by the sheet changing name or position
 'Example:
 ws.Name = "NewSheetName"
 MsgBox "The sheet at position " & ws.Index & " has changed names and is now called " & ws.Name

 'Rest of the code
```

Comment: This seems to good. It technically not part of what this question asks but this is the error I'm getting now  Object required error at "colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula".

Comment: I don't see any code setting the `ws1` and `ws2` variables. You're referring to empty variables. You can see how I have set my `ws` variable before referring to it

Comment: All I know is that colval1  is supposed to get the value of that row in wk1( worksheet1) and then we compare that row from both worksheets If colval1 <> colval2 . if they are different then do  change the font and the other stuff

Comment: Look at my code and how I declare and set a worksheet variable. This variable is a reference to the specific worksheet you set it to. You're supposedly trying to use worksheet variables with `ws1` and `ws2`, but you never set these (link them to worksheets)

Comment: Let me add that using `Option Explicit` would be a great starting point. This forces you to declare every variable and thus makes sure you don't make any spelling mistakes or empty references. The compiler will immediately realise `ws1` and `ws2` are nonsense variables before the code executes

Comment: I have gone through your adjusment and the advice you have given. Now I have to declare ws1 as variable of sheet1 and ws2 as variable of sheet2. how do I do this considering that sheet1 and sheet2 are already created

Comment: I don't understand the problem because "Sheet1" is also already created. Regardless, read the link

Comment: if  you can fix the code so I dont get the error at colval1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula   so the line actually gets the data from first sheet .That would mean a lot because at this point the comments are just confusing me, if not. I still appreaciate a lot your help. thank u

Comment: The solution is in my answer... I press you to read it line by line with the commented text. You can't use `ws1` ***without actually linking the variable to the worksheet you mean to refer to***. Look at my code, see how I linked `ws` to a specific worksheet?

Comment: You can check the changes I did on the code above. Now I'm getting the error: index outside the valid range at  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("Sheet1")
```

to this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Same for Sheet2

Comment: thank you for the answer. Now I get an error at "With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")"  saying index outside the valid range

Comment: Is there a sheet called "Sheet1"? or is it called "Sheet 1" (with a space)?

Comment: I have a gave a comment above.