# Filling cells of the correct workbook when multiple copies are open

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I´m using VBA userforms to fill values from the textboxes into cells of a specific sheet. Lets says the Sheet is named "Sheet1", the textbox is called "TextBox1" and the cell is "C2". I´m currently using

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("c2").value = Userform1.TextBox1.Value
```

to fill the cell with the value that I have typed into the textbox. Now I have experienced that when I have multiple copies of the same document opened, it doesnt always put the value in the intended document, but into the copy (which also has a sheet called "Sheet1"). Is there a way around that problem?

Comment: If **multiple copies** means different names, `ThisWorkbook` **will always refer the workbook where the running code exists**. Then, a sheet named **Sheet1** and `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1` can be different in some circumstances. Worksheet **name** and worksheet **code name** may be different... But if what you show is not true, and the code uses `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1` instead of `ThisWorkbook.Sheet1`, it will use `sheet1` of the **Active Workbook**.

Comment: Please, read [Difference between Thisworkbook.name and Activeworkbook.name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426907/difference-between-thisworkbook-name-and-activeworkbook-name-in-vba)